# Get NTFS Access Rights

Tags: powershell, acl

I'm looking for a way to list all access rights from a folder recursively.
Right now I have this Code:

```
$logfile = "C:\temp\test.txt"
$testpath = "H:\"

dir $testpath -Recurse | Get-Acl | Out-File $logfile
```

But this doesn't list all access rights.

Does anyone have a idea what wrong is?

**EDIT:**
At the moment it looks like this:

```
Boardmaker
HEALTH\infsst_sys
VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren Allow  FullControl...
```

Comment: What "*doesn't list all access-rights*" means? What's missing or what error message are you getting?

Comment: It lists the first accessrole and the rights, but then it only writes "...."

Comment: Please describe it in your question, as it's now, it's not very clear, what's wrong or missing.

Comment: The output is shortened to fit into your (hypothetical) display. Probably looping through the properties would help.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Acl` produces a complex data structure with owner and access information about an object. You need to expand the `Access` property of that object to get the information you want:

```
Get-ChildItem $testpath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $file = $_.FullName
  Get-Acl -Path $file | Select-Object -Expand Access |
    Select-Object @{n='File';e={$file}}, IdentityReference, FileSystemRights,
                  AccessControlType
} | Export-Csv $logfile -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks way better. But still, it gets cut off....
Like this:
NT-AUTORITÄT\Authentifizierte...

Comment: Ah, that's because the output gets auto-formatted before being written to the file. Export the data to a CSV instead.